# PyMC3 %-th leading minor of the array is not positive definite

Tags: python, machine-learning, gaussian, bayesian, pymc3

I am trying to configure PyMC3 Polynomial kernel with the following hyperpriors;

```
    with pm.Model() as self.model:
      EPSILON = 0.1 
      l = pm.Gamma("l", alpha=2, beta=1)
      offset = pm.Gamma("offset", alpha=2, beta=1)
      nu = pm.HalfCauchy("nu", beta=1)
      d = pm.HalfNormal("d", sd=5)

      cov = nu ** 2 * pm.gp.cov.Polynomial(X.shape[1], l, d, offset)

      self.gp = pm.gp.Marginal(cov_func=cov)

      sigma = pm.HalfCauchy("sigma", beta=1)
      y_ = self.gp.marginal_likelihood("y", X=X, y=Y, noise=sigma)

      self. map_trace = [pm.find_MAP()]
```

However, I'm getting *Cholesky decomposition failed*  error as follows;

```
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    902             outputs =\
--> 903                 self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
    904                 self.fn(output_subset=output_subset)

24 frames
LinAlgError: 7-th leading minor of the array is not positive definite

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp_cholesky.py in _cholesky(a, lower, overwrite_a, clean, check_finite)
     38     if info > 0:
     39         raise LinAlgError("%d-th leading minor of the array is not positive "
---> 40                           "definite" % info)
     41     if info < 0:
     42         raise ValueError('LAPACK reported an illegal value in {}-th argument'

LinAlgError: 7-th leading minor of the array is not positive definite
Apply node that caused the error: Cholesky{lower=True, destructive=False, on_error='raise'}(Elemwise{Composite{((sqr(i0) * i1) + i2 + i3)}}[(0, 0)].0)
Toposort index: 11
Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(40, 40)]
Inputs strides: [(320, 8)]
Inputs values: ['not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Solve{A_structure='lower_triangular', lower=False, overwrite_A=False, overwrite_b=False}(Cholesky{lower=True, destructive=False, on_error='raise'}.0, TensorConstant{[  69.79  ..   472.83]}), Solve{A_structure='lower_triangular', lower=False, overwrite_A=False, overwrite_b=False}(Cholesky{lower=True, destructive=False, on_error='raise'}.0, Elemwise{Composite{(sqr(i0) * i1)}}[(0, 0)].0)]]
```

Changing the hyperpriors seems to change the error like instead of 7th leading minor it will show some other x-th leading minor. But I'm not sure if this is caused by hyperpriors or something else.

Any thoughts are welcome :)

Thanks

Comment: You may find more specific help via [the PyMC Discourse](https://discourse.pymc.io/).

Comment: Thanks @merv I did post it there and got some feedback. For anyone interested: [Visit here](https://discourse.pymc.io/t/th-leading-minor-of-the-array-is-not-positive-definite/6127/5)

Comment: Thanks for following back up! and feel free to write up an answer to summarize what you settled on and mark it as the solution.

Comment: How did you solve it? I tried to specify the hyper-parameters but no luck. It was suggested also to increase the jitter but I have no such parameters in the `gp`. It happens mainly when I invoke `predict` method.